# PhpStorm spellchecking in commit message?

Tags: git, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

According to the [Proofreading section in the official docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/proofreading.html), it is stated, that commit messaged will be validated, when set in the grammar configs.

I do have the Grazie plugin installed (as required [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/grammar.html#rules)).

I do have "Commit messages enabled in the Grammar scope:

[image]

However, there is are no spellchecks in my commit message:

[image]

I also have checkked spelling in "commit message inspections":
[image]

I am using Version 2020.3.2. Have I done something wrong?

Comment: Please check if you have "Spelling" inspection enabled in "Version Control | Commit > Commit Message Inspections".

Comment: @duck_in_hat yes I have it enabled. Added screenshot to the question

Comment: I do have a disabled `Commit messages` checkbox. However spellchecking works for me. What about `Editor | Inspections > Proofreading > Typo`? Is that option selected for you?

Comment: @PavloZhukov you have `Commit messages` unchecked in the grammer screen, but he spellchecks your commit messages? All options are selected at `Editor | Inspections > Proofreading > Typo`